# TextView: onDraw getting called only once

Tags: java, android, textview, android-custom-view

I have a situation where I want to debug calls to `TextView.onDraw()` so I subclassed it like this:

```
public class MyTextView extends AppCompatTextView {

    View parent;

    public MyTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public void storeParent(View parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

and put it up inside a hierarchy like this:(see `MyTextView`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.scrollviewtest1.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/scroll_container"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.example.scrollviewtest1.MyTextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/large_text" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!" />

    </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

Lastly, I put a very large piece of text for this `TextView` so that it becomes scrollable.

Now, if I put a breakpoint inside the `onDraw()` method, I only get one call to it. As per my understanding, I should be getting call to it as I scroll up and down. Why is this happening?

**Side note:** I have already tried setting `setWillNotDraw(false)` with no change in the outcome.

Comment: Normally, you should not make assumptions on the count of invocation of `onDraw()` method. Why do you need that to be called?

Comment: @azizbekian : For testing purposes; not production

Comment: @azizbekian : But, it should get called logically, when you scroll up or dodwn

Comment: You can use `text2.invalidate();` .

Comment: `But, it should get called logically, when you scroll up or down` Agree, I also expect `onDraw()` to be called, but maybe because that view is inside `ScrollView` and you just perform scrolling, then only the `DisplayList` of `TextView` is being updated, which results in an optimization of not calling each children's `onDraw()` method, I am not sure about this.

Comment: @azizbekian : Well that would be very interesting and insightful, if true

Comment: @KeLiuyue : Well, that's true - that will definitely work and indeed it did but would be highly useful if I could know the actual reason behind only one call

Comment: simply turn the hardware acceleration off and your `onDraw` method will be called each time you scroll

Comment: @pskink : Well, that's the trick! I manually put `<application android:hardwareAccelerated="false">` and it is off now for real and `onDraw()` is getting called every time without explicit `invalidate()`. BTW, do you have any idea, how H/W acceleration plays part in the picture? Thanks

Comment: next time pay more attention on comments you receive and you will save a lot of your time

Comment: @pskink : I did! I checked the device as well as the appliation tag for it. By default, it is disabled and that's true except for Android version 6.x, it is enabled. For that, I had to put android:hardwareAccelerated="false" explicitly..

Comment: @pskink : I mistakenly replied to this comment in other question of mine but other than that I did check for it. It has a caveat that is a twist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit goes to @pskink for suggesting turning off H/W acceleration for this; it worked. Here is what [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#unsupported) say about this:

> ### Hardware accelerated drawing model
>
> The Android system still uses invalidate() and draw() to request
>   screen updates and to render views, but handles the actual drawing
>   differently. Instead of executing the drawing commands immediately,
>   the Android system records them inside display lists, which contain
>   the output of the view hierarchy’s drawing code. Another optimization
>   is that the Android system only needs to record and update display
>   lists for views marked dirty by an invalidate() call. Views that have
>   not been invalidated can be redrawn simply by re-issuing the
>   previously recorded display list. The new drawing model contains three
>   stages:
>
> ```
> Invalidate the hierarchy
> Record and update display lists
> Draw the display lists
> ```
>
> With this model, you cannot rely on a view intersecting the dirty
>   region to have its draw() method executed. To ensure that the Android
>   system records a view’s display list, you must call invalidate().
>   Forgetting to do so causes a view to look the same even after it has
>   been changed.
>
> Using display lists also benefits animation performance because
>   setting specific properties, such as alpha or rotation, does not
>   require invalidating the targeted view (it is done automatically).
>   This optimization also applies to views with display lists (any view
>   when your application is hardware accelerated.) For example, assume
>   there is a LinearLayout that contains a ListView above a Button. The
>   display list for the LinearLayout looks like this:
>
> ```
> DrawDisplayList(ListView)
> DrawDisplayList(Button)
> ```
>
> Assume now that you want to change the ListView's opacity. After
>   invoking setAlpha(0.5f) on the ListView, the display list now contains
>   this:
>
> ```
> SaveLayerAlpha(0.5)
> DrawDisplayList(ListView)
> Restore
> DrawDisplayList(Button)
> ```
>
> The complex drawing code of ListView was not executed. Instead, the
>   system only updated the display list of the much simpler LinearLayout.
>   In an application without hardware acceleration enabled, the drawing
>   code of both the list and its parent are executed again.

**VS**

> ### Software-based drawing model
>
> In the software drawing model, views are drawn with the following two
>   steps:
>
> ```
> Invalidate the hierarchy
> Draw the hierarchy
> ```
>
> Whenever an application needs to update a part of its UI, it invokes
>   invalidate() (or one of its variants) on any view that has changed
>   content. The invalidation messages are propagated all the way up the
>   view hierarchy to compute the regions of the screen that need to be
>   redrawn (the dirty region). The Android system then draws any view in
>   the hierarchy that intersects with the dirty region. Unfortunately,
>   there are two drawbacks to this drawing model:
>
> ```
> First, this model requires execution of a lot of code on every draw pass. For example, if your application calls invalidate() on a
> ```
>
> button and that button sits on top of another view, the Android system
>   redraws the view even though it hasn't changed.
>       The second issue is that the drawing model can hide bugs in your application. Since the Android system redraws views when they
>   intersect the dirty region, a view whose content you changed might be
>   redrawn even though invalidate() was not called on it. When this
>   happens, you are relying on another view being invalidated to obtain
>   the proper behavior. This behavior can change every time you modify
>   your application. Because of this, you should always call invalidate()
>   on your custom views whenever you modify data or state that affects
>   the view’s drawing code.
>
> **Note:** Android views automatically call invalidate() when their properties change, such as the background color or the text in a
>   TextView.