# View.getTop() always returns 0

Tags: android

So `View.getTop()` is, as per the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTop()):

> Top position of this view relative to its parent.

I have the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.scrollviewtest1.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/scroll_container"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.example.scrollviewtest1.MyTextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/large_text" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!" />

    </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

I am checking for `getTop()` for `LinearLayout` as I scroll up and down and `getTop()` always returns 0. Shouldn't it change as ***it moves up and down relative to its parent?***.

**How I checked it?**

I stored reference to the `LinearLayout` inside the child `TextView` and called `invalidate()` every time there was scrolling:

```
ScrollView root = ((ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.root));
        root.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChanged() {
                textView.invalidate();
            }
        });
```

and checked inside the `onDraw()` call of the child `TextView`

Comment: Put delay for few seconds and then check.

Comment: @Jaymin : Can you elaborate a bit more on it? How?

Comment: How do you check it? Could be something there that explains it

Comment: Can you please post your code? so i can check it and explain you.

Comment: @Zoe : I have added the part as to how I check it.

Comment: @Jaymin : I have posted the code. Do you need any more than that?

Comment: `Shouldn't it change as it moves up and down relative to its parent?.` no, only the scroll ofset changes in outer `ScrollView`

Comment: @pskink: Well, then the `getTop()` of the `TextView` should at least change if not the `LinearLayout`. That is also returning 0 all the time.

Comment: no, no layout management is performed while scrolling, only the scroll offset changes in outer `ScrollView`

Comment: @pskink : Fine. Let's say you are right. Logically, scrolling is changing the position of Views. So, shouldn't it lead to changes in layout? If not, what is the reason for that?

Comment: why the layout should change at all? does the parent view size change? does any child view size change? is any child view removed or added? no, so why the layout should change?

Comment: what actually do you want to achieve? did you turn the hardware acceleration off as i said or not?

Comment: @pskink : I want to use this value to update some other `View`

Comment: did you turn the hardware acceleration off as i said or not? did you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46987711/textview-ondraw-getting-called-only-once#comment80923227_46987711) at all?

Comment: @pskink : I think its turned off in the device by default: https://imgur.com/a/1qXiR. It is not enabled programmatically(using `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"`) either.

Comment: `hardware accelerated rendering` is "On" - you have to turn hwd accell **off** (either on app level or activity level or view level)

Comment: @pskink : Oh no no. That's developers option that's on. On my Samsung device, there is a Switch to enable developers options.(the switch in the piccture). You got confused because it is "together" with the scrolled down options.

Comment: @pskink : i just checked the manifest and its not turned on in the applcation tag.

Comment: so what does `View.isHardwareAccelerated()` return? what does `Canvas.isHardwareAccelerated()` return?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int top = view.getTop();
        }

    }, 300);// delay times in milliseconds
```

You can set delay time as per your requirement.

Comment: Just tried it. It displays 0 as I scroll up and down

Answer (score 0):

To get the LinearLayout scrolled position call `myScrollView.getScrollY();`

`getTop();` returns what you entered as marginTop in your xml layout and it not varies when the thing is scrolled, to know the actual current position you need to take in account `getScrollY();` too

Comment: I have added margin to the `LinearLayout` and its giving me now the exact margin amount I added as `getTop()`. I saw that `ScrollView extends Framelayout`. How is it different really to not give a proper value for `getTop()`?